# How can I pass through low height tunnels?

Tags: dust-an-elysian-tail

Through the game there are several places where there is a low height corridor. It seems that the character could roll but I'm failing to do so. How can I go through these tunnels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have the ability to crawl/roll yet.

Just keep doing the story for a bit. You will come across a way to get in those low height corridors.